# Adding new DataSource in runtime

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc

I am not a very experienced java programmer and may have very simple questions. Before I describe the problem let me explain the architecture:

1. We need an app in the cloud
2. We have four customers, each customer have their own MySQL DB instance (4 DBs in total). This is mainly for political as well as some performance reasons (certain reads take up to 20 seconds to execute, an INSERT-statement is performed every one or two seconds)
3. The app will run on two VM instances for fail-over and better performance, ie. DataSource will be dynamic as any of the two app instances may target one of the database instances
4. We plan to have one configuration DB for all customers, used as an internal repository for the app. Here we maintain users and other configurations, activity monitoring, etc

Whenever we add a new customer the app should not have to be restarted, hence configuration DB. In this DB we plan to keep a DataSource per user and perform a lookup whenever a RESTful-service is called (may call it stateless DataSource). The only additional thing to do is to add new MySQL instance.
The main frameworks/tools we use are java, Spring (JdbcTemplate), HikariCP (JDBC connection pool) and Tomcat.

**We have following questions:**

1. What is the relationship between a connection pool and javax.sql.DataSource, ie. since we plan to recreate DataSource for each RESTful-method call  will this destroy an existing connection pool to database X?
2. What is the best way to achieve dynamic DataSource in Spring when DataSources are specified in configuration DB (I did read the following [link](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) explaining dynamic DataSource defined in a config file, not supporting adding new sources in runtime)

Kind regards
A.H.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the relationship between a connection pool and javax.sql.DataSource, ie. since we plan to recreate DataSource for each RESTful-method call will this destroy an existing connection pool to database X?

A DB connection pool is not necessarily a JDBC construct.  Instead various implementations of JDBC DB connection pools have appeared. The Tomcat one specifically might not easily be used to add dynamic runtime DataSources (I have not done it myself so don't know for sure).  But there are others that exist that do allow this.  For example vibur is a DB connection pool that allows users to add DataSources during runtime.

```
public DataSource createDataSourceWithStatementsCache() {
    ViburDBCPDataSource ds = new ViburDBCPDataSource();

    ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:sakila;shutdown=false");
    ds.setUsername("sa");
    ds.setPassword("");

    ds.setPoolInitialSize(10);
    ds.setPoolMaxSize(100);

    ds.setConnectionIdleLimitInSeconds(30);
    ds.setTestConnectionQuery("isValid");

    ds.setLogQueryExecutionLongerThanMs(500);
    ds.setLogStackTraceForLongQueryExecution(true);

    ds.setStatementCacheMaxSize(200);

    ds.start();
    return ds;
}
```

That method came from the vibur [website](http://www.vibur.org/#features-and-characteristics).  I have used them in past in performance critical application with great success.  It could be the case that the connection pool will detect duplicates but if not you can add to that method a check in some sort of HashSet to see if the DataSource with that username/pw/connectionString already exists.

> What is the best way to achieve dynamic DataSource in Spring when DataSources are specified in configuration DB (I did read the following link explaining dynamic DataSource defined in a config file, not supporting adding new sources in runtime)

In the past I worked on a project that had to use runtime DataSources.  It is not that hard.  This is how we did it.  All you basically need is a table with the connection string, the driver (if multiple DB's are required and drivers are loaded dynamically, probably not an issue for your case), and credentials.  You can enhance your table with more attributes like number of connections and so forth and so on.  Then all you need is an ID that you can use to lookup this information.

When a request comes in, you can check get the DB ID from either the request or poll it from a cache-source or anywhere really.  Then using that DB ID you can lookup the DB connection info and create the DataSource using the method described above.  Obviously you will use caching to avoid DB calls... this data is pretty static info and does not need to be retrieved on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
public static DataSource getDataSource() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myContext.xml");
    return (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSource");
}
```

and myContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: this is a too simple solution without a pool. What will happen to the existing pool in memory when you recreate a datasource with same url, user and password?